# How do I get the Html Element (or Locker API SecureElement) for a child LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

In an LWC component, `this.template.querySelector()` appears to return an Element (or probably SecureElement) for standard HTML elements, but something else for child components.  For example:

```
this.template.querySelector('div').scrollIntoView();
```

This will find the first div and correctly scroll it into view.  On the other hand:

```
this.template.querySelector('c-child').scrollIntoView();
```

does not work.  I can verify that `this.template.querySelector('c-child')` is indeed returning an object that represents the first `c-child` custom LWC component, and the call to `scrollIntoView()` does not return an error, but the display does not move.  I assume that the object return is not the SecureElement representing the `<c-child>` node in my `<template>`.

I am able to get the desired behavior by adding a public api method to `c-child`:

```
@api
scrollToHere() {
    this.template.querySelector('div').scrollIntoView();
}
```

and calling it from the parent, e.g.,

```
this.template.querySelector('c-child').scrollToHere();
```

But this seems unnecessary since there should be a element in the DOM to represent the `<c-child>` element, but either `.querySelector('c-child')` doesn't return that element, or LWC elements don't support standard SecureElement methods such as `.scrollIntoView()`.  I tried a few variations such as `this.template.querySelector('c-child').element.scrollIntoView();` without success.